# How to use --force-dev-mode-highlighting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am able to run an extension on browser but a warning "Disable Developer Mode" always block the test case to complete which I resolve by manually clicking to cancel button. I know a command line switch that will disable this warning --force-dev-mode-highlighting but don't know how to use this

Do someone know how?

Following is the code I used to open chrome with extension.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl\\2.2_0\\Full-Page-Screen-Capture_v2.2.crx"));      
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Are you sure you load an extension through `options.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Users\\abc\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl\\2.2_0\\Full-Page-Screen-Capture_v2.2.crx"));` Can you direct me to some documentation please?

Comment: @Dev http://www.testingexcellence.com/webdriver-tutorial-open-browser-extensions/

Comment: I think your question Header & Description does not match & you may like to edit. Your Question should be `How to run an extension in Google Chrome`. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I am able to run an extension in chrome, the problem I am facing is of that disable developer mode warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **--force-dev-mode-highlighting** switch by invoking an **addArguments** method that's in the **ChromeOptions** class:

```
options.addArguments("--force-dev-mode-highlighting");
```

However, this switch does not prevent the warning message from showing up.

If the following are used, then Chrome can be run with at least one extension enabled and without the warning (and the code that you've provided will work without the issue occurring):
1. [V̲e̲r̲s̲i̲o̲n̲ ̲3̲.̲3̲.̲1](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.3/selenium-java-3.3.1.zip) of the Selenium Java Client Driver
2. [C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲D̲r̲i̲v̲e̲r̲ ̲2̲.̲2̲8](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/)
3. [C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲ ̲5̲8̲.̲0̲.̲3̲0̲2̲9̲.̲8̲1](https://www.neowin.net/news/google-chrome-58-released-now-available-for-download)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I updated Version of ChromeDriver to 2.29 and that warning problem resolved.